# Pagination with a POST

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a field where a user can search in. The user selects an option, then that is posted to a view and returns him with the Filtered results on a new page.

Im not sure how I would paginate this because the data this must be displayed is filtered by the previous post?

To paginate the first one is fine, cause tou have the post and know what to return to the page. But what about page 2 etc? then the post is gone?

Comment: I could use GET also, the probably save the get request some home?But Im hoping there's a more elegant solution

Comment: You'll probably want to use GET. If it's just a search and doesn't change any state on the server side, GET is the correct method to user. Use POST when you're doing non-idempotent operations (as a generic rule of thumb).

Comment: Thank you for the comment.I changed to get now, Ill keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hidden HTML input fields to keep track values posted from previous post

Comment: and the same with a GET request?

Comment: what about saving the url with the get parameters ?